# double each helper doesn't fire observed property group.cards.[] [jsbin]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I made a jsbin to reproduce the problem but the bug doesn't happen on jsbin.
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mamunecene/edit?html,js,output.

I have this double each helper template:

```
   {{#each group in groups}}
     {{#each card in group.cards}}
        {{#play-card card=card group=group}}{{/play-card}}<br/>
     {{/each}}
   {{/each}}
```

problem is `play-card` component:

```
App.PlayCardComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  number: function() {
    return this.get('card.number');
  }.property('card'),

  index: function() {
    var card = this.get('card');
    var cards = this.get('group.cards');
    var idx = cards.indexOf(card);

    return idx;
  }.property('card', 'group.cards.[]')
});
```

Notice the `index` property is observing `group.cards.[]`. So whenever a new card is added/removed from the group all the cards in that group should update their indexes.

In the jsbin It works fine. But it fails to fire in my real example. What could be the problem there.

Note that i am sure this is the same problem because I have this workaround to force update all the cards in the group:

```
refreshModels: function() {
  var cards = this.get('cards');
  var tempCards = [];

  cards.forEach(function(card) {
    tempCards.push(card);
  });

  tempCards.forEach(function(card) {
    cards.removeObject(card);
    cards.addObject(card);
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for adding and removing cards from the array? Remember to use .pushObject and .removeObject or observers of the array will not be notified

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to find a bug in working example, but sometimes it helps to observe more properties than you think you may need. Please try:

```
index: function() {
    var card = this.get('card');
    var cards = this.get('group.cards');
    if (!card || !cards) {
        return;
    }
    var idx = cards.indexOf(card);

    return idx;
}.property('card', 'group', 'group.cards', 'group.cards.[]')
```

Check in your console if you have any errors, check if you're running same Ember version as in JS Bin demo, check Ember Data version.